# SQL Server connection from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2016 database from Excel (Office 365).

First of all :

- I can ping the SQL Server from my PC
- I can telnet SQL Server 1433
- I can connect to the SQL Server with a SQL Server account
- I got the credential popup when I connect from Excel (tried with domain account and SQL Server account).
- There is no firewall restriction between client and server.

But finally I got this error message:

[image]

Where should I check ?

Comment: Check your ODBC connection and credentials?

Comment: Not sure i need ODBC for this. But where can i check this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm using IP adress instead of server name and it is working. So it should be a DNS issue.